Awk matching patterns and removing adjacent lines
I've got the volumetric data from different brain regions and I'm trying to sort it out to make the analysis easier. To get an idea this is a part of what I've got:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100

I want modify it and the output would be:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100

Just want to have this "overlaps" line in each record.
I'm rather a newbie in programming but I came up with something like that:
awk '{
    if (NR == 1) {
        # Initialize the first region (using first world in a line)
        region = $1
        print $0
    } else {
        if ($1 != region) {
            # Finalize the old region - printing "overlaps" line with 0 0
            printf("%s %overlaps 0 0\n", region)
            # Start the new region
            region = $1
        }
        # Print the current line (for the current region)
        print $0

    }
}
END {
    # For the last region
    if (region) {
        printf("%s 0 0\n", region)
    }
}'

The outcome is close to what I want:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 0 0
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100

But I've these extra "overlaps" lines in regions which already had it.
Could you please help me? What should I do to make it work?
I'd be very grateful for any help!!
Thanks
Marcin

A not entirely serious contribution: tac your_file | awk '{if ($2=="overlaps"){ print; getline; print } else { print $1, "overlaps 0 0"; print }}' | tac

Are the $1 pre-sorted?

@Cyrus a tac solution was my first thought too: tac | awk '{ if ($2!=v) print $1,v,0,0; else {print;getline} } 1' v=overlap | tac

Assumptions/Understandings:

input file is already sorted by the 1st field
for a given value in the 1st field there will be at most 2 lines in the input file with said value
for a given value in the 1st field and only one input line containing said value, said line will not contain the string "overlaps"
for a given value in the 1st field there will be exactly 2 lines in the output with said value

One awk idea:
awk '
    { if ($1 != prev && NR > 1 && ! overlaps)       # if different $1 and previous line did not contain string "overlaps" then ...    
         print prev,"overlaps",0,0                  # print new line
      overlaps = ($2 == "overlaps" ? 1 : 0)         # set flag
      prev = $1                                     # save current $1
    }
1                                                   # print current line
END { if (! overlaps)                               # if last line of file did not contain string "overlaps" then ...  
         print prev,"overlaps",0,0                  # print new line
    }
' volume.dat

This generates:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100


To demonstrate correct processing where the last line is not an "overlaps" line:
Setup:
$ cat volume.dat
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100
XX_Last_Line 1234 6789.00000

The same code generates:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100
XX_Last_Line 1234 6789.00000
XX_Last_Line overlaps 0 0


Using any awk that retains the value of $2 in the END section (most do):
$ awk '
    { addOverlaps(); print }
    END { addOverlaps() }

    function addOverlaps() {
        if ( (numOutLines++ % 2) && ($2 != "overlaps") ) {
            print prevRegion, "overlaps", 0, 0
            numOutLines++
        }
        prevRegion = $1
    }
' file
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100


awk '{ if ($1!=col1 && col1!=""){ 
           print col1 " overlaps 0 0"; }; 
       col1=$1; 
     }
     /overlaps/{ col1="" }
     1' input.txt


When the first column ($1) is not equal to the variable col1, and this variable has content, then print this with " overlaps 0 0"
Then assign col1 with the value from the current first column.
When the line contains "overlaps" (/overlaps/) reset the col1 variable.
Finally print the line (1)

output:
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100


Better use: $2=="overlaps"{ col1="" } instead of a regex

@GillesQuénot: That might work too. but My return question would be: Why? If it is only because of performance, than I would not do it .... (But you will have better reasons for not using the regular expression)

To prevent matching another columns. Better not using regex when it's not necessary

last line of file is not finalized with this code

/overlaps/ would match LT_Boverlapsis if such a string could appear in the input.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100

then
awk 'NR==FNR&&$2=="overlaps"{arr[$1]=$0}NR!=FNR&&$2!="overlaps"{print $0;print ($1 in arr)?arr[$1]:($1 " overlaps 0 0")}' file.txt file.txt

gives output
LT_Putamen 5075 5075.000000
LT_Putamen overlaps 0 0
LT_Temporal 84593 84593.000000
LT_Temporal overlaps 0 0
LT_Thalamus 7720 7720.000000
LT_Thalamus overlaps 0 0
RT_Accumbens 623 623.000000
RT_Accumbens overlaps 64.000000 10.2700
RT_Amygdala 2252 2252.000000
RT_Amygdala overlaps 2133.000000 94.7100

Explanation: this is 2-pass solution, hence file.txt is repeated. In first pass (i.e. where number of row NR is equal to file number of row FNR are equal) for line where 2nd field is overlaps I store whole line ($0) as value in array under key being 1st field. For 2nd pass (NR and FNR being different) for non overlaps lines I print whole line ($0) and if there is key corresponding to 1st field in array arr value for that field, otherwise 1st field concatenated with  overlaps 0 0. In order to do so I use so-called ternary operator condition?valueiftrue:valueiffalse.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
